# Comparison of Variances of Expectation Conditioned on More Random Variables

Tags: conditional-expectation, independence, variance

I want to compare (if possible) the following two terms: (1) $\mathrm{Var}(\mathrm{E}[Y | X_1])$ and (2) $\mathrm{Var}(\mathrm{E}[Y | X_1, X_2])$. If they are not comparable as they are, the following assumptions can also be made (each is a seperate case):

- $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.
- $X_1$ and $X_2$ are jointly Gaussian and each has standard distribution with $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

I think both (1) and (2) are constants and there should be a way to compare them. I do not know where to start. Any leads to a solution will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, $\mathrm{Var}(E(Z\mid\mathcal G))\leqslant\mathrm{Var}(Z)$. Apply this to $Z=E(Y\mid X_1)$ and $\mathcal G=\sigma(X_1,X_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is $\sigma$ the covariance of $X_1$ and $X_2$?

Comment: No, this denotes the generated sigma-algebra.

Comment: $$\sigma(X_1,X_2) = \sigma\left(\sigma(X_1)\cup\sigma(X_2) \right) $$ where in general $$\sigma(X) = \sigma(\{X^{-1}(B):B\in\mathcal B \}, $$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Now I understand the solution.